# Shorewall missing from Ubuntu 11.10 default repository?

Tags: apt, debian

I'm looking to configure my network using Shorewall on my Ubuntu 11.10 laptop.

When I run `apt-cache search` it doesn't find Shorewall, is there some other repository I can add it from?

Or is the [Debian package listed on the Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/download.htm) website compatible with Ubuntu 11.10,  since Ubuntu is Debian-based?

Comment: It has not been taken out... http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=shorewall&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all ... so it must be something wrong with your configuration

Comment: I ended up adding the author's repository to it as specified on his page: http://people.connexer.com/~roberto/debian/  I had to do a few things, like add his repository to my software updates and  import a gpg key into apt-get so that I could search for shorewall.

Comment: Have you got universe packages enabled (In software center go to Edit ⇒ Software sources ⇒ Ubuntu software, look for a line with universe in it.)

Comment: Should I close this out or just answer my own question?

Comment: Answer your own question. It's fine. You may need to wait before accepting your own answer.

Comment: @Portablejim Your answer seems better (on the whole) so how about you answer my question and I'll select it as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is [still in the repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=shorewall&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all). So it must be something wrong with your installation.

Have you got 'universe' packages enabled? You can check by going to

```
Edit ⇒ Software sources ⇒ Ubuntu software
```

and looking for a line with `universe` in it.

Afterwards you will need to reload the repository information (e.g. with `apt-get update`).